# Efeito jquery não funciona por causa dos parentes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Preciso abrir o `id="SUB_1"` quando eu clicar no `<li id="B1">Botão 1</li>`
e fazer o mesmo quando eu clicar no `<li id="B1">Botão 2</li>` abrir o `id="SUB_1"` que esta abaixo do botão q foi clicado. E fazer o msm com o 3 também, Mas apenas com aquele jquery que coloquei no final.

```
$(function(){
   $(".Principal").click(function(){
      $(this). ???
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="Principal">
        <li id="B1">Botão 1</li>
    </ol>

    <ol id="SUB_1">
        <li id="A1">1</li>
        <li id="A2">2</li>
        <li id="A3">3</li>
    </ol>


    <ol class="Principal">
        <li id="B1">Botão 2</li>
    </ol>

    <ol id="SUB_1">
        <li id="A4">4</li>
        <li id="A5">5</li>
        <li id="A6">6</li>
    </ol>


    <ol class="Principal">
        <li id="B1">Botão 3</li>
    </ol>

    <ol id="SUB_1">
        <li id="A7">7</li>
        <li id="A8">8</li>
        <li id="A9">9</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Algumas considerações: ao contrário das classes, o id é utilizado para apenas um elemento. Assim, você deve redesignar os ids dos botões para b1, b2, b3, bX e os das listas para sub1, sub2, sub3, etc.

Comment: No JQuery, o event listener (click) poderia ser com relação ao id do botão clicado (ex: #b1) ao invés da classe do pai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É incorreto usar vários `ids` para mais de um elemento. Mas como você está pegando o click pela classe `.Principal`, você pode referenciar o elemento que vem logo abaixo com `.next()`. Apenas para ilustração, criei uma classe para visualizar o efeito:

```js
$(function(){
   $(".Principal").click(function(){
      $(this).next().addClass("red");
   });
});
```

```css
.red{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="Principal">
   <li id="B1">Botão 1</li>
</ol>

<ol id="SUB_1">
   <li id="A1">1</li>
   <li id="A2">2</li>
   <li id="A3">3</li>
</ol>

<ol class="Principal">
   <li id="B1">Botão 2</li>
</ol>

<ol id="SUB_1">
   <li id="A4">4</li>
   <li id="A5">5</li>
   <li id="A6">6</li>
</ol>

<ol class="Principal">
   <li id="B1">Botão 3</li>
</ol>

<ol id="SUB_1">
   <li id="A7">7</li>
   <li id="A8">8</li>
   <li id="A9">9</li>
</ol>
```

> Mas recomendo corrigir seu código tirando essas várias `ids`. Você
>   pode usar `class` em vez de `id`.

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".B1").click(function(){
    $('.B1')($(this).parents('ol').next().slideToggle(200));
});
```

Consegui dessa maneira.

Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar e que deram dicas vlw